# Postgresql json field has dates in both YYYY-MM-DD and 13 digit unix timestamp format

Tags: json, regex, postgresql, date

I am parsing a json array and one field I am pulling out is closedate. However closedate has two different date formats one is YYYY-MM-DD and the other is a 13 digit timestamp. I am trying to get consistent formatting of the dates as well as have it be an integer compared to a string. Right now the query returning the close date is:

`json_array_elements(ld.data->'Table1'->'Details')->>'closeDate' as closedate`

and it returns close date as a string:

| id | closedate |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-09-29 |
| 2 | 1606824000000 |

Someone was telling me to do something like a case statement with regex. But I am not familiar with regex function. Any help is appreciated.

Edit: I have

```
case when x.closedate::text ~* '^[0-9]{13}$' then 
                 to_timestamp(x.closedate::bigint/1000)
                 when x.closedate = '0' then null
                 when x.closedate = '' then null
            else 
                 to_date(x.closedate,'MMDDYYYY') end as transactionclosedate
```

the case statement works for converting the 13 digit timestamp to a date but I am getting the error:

ERROR: date/time field value out of range: "2020-10-23"

when trying to convert the date strings in the correct format to dates in the else part of the case statement.

Comment: What have you attempted so far?

Comment: please share a sample dataset that others can use to build a solution.

Comment: I present an answer below for this situation, but the longer term solution is not get in this situation in the first place. If at all possible: a) Settle on a consistent timestamp  format for all records b) Store records in a table not JSON so you can enforce type.

Comment: @WaisKamal I have  ```case when x.closedate::text similar to '^[0-9]+$' then      to_timestamp(x.closedate::bigint/1000)::date   else      x.closedate::date end as transactionclosedate'``` but am getting an error message: date/time field value out of range: "1605657600000"

Comment: Your input format does not match the the specified input format within the t_date_function.  The expression  `to_date(x.closedate,'MMDDYYYY')` requires the data be in the specified format, but the data is not in that format. Try   `to_date(x.closedate,'yyyy-mm-dd')`.

Comment: @Belayer I did that and now getting the error message: ERROR: invalid value "‎2" for "yyyy" Detail: Value must be an integer.

Comment: Please post the **complete** statement and the **complete** error message.   Also post your actual **complete input set**. Your posted error is inconsistent with the statement. The error indicates it must be a an integer, yet to_date requires  text.

Answer (score 1):

An example of one way to make this work. My regex skills are not strong so others may have a better solution:

```
create table regex_test (id int, fld_1 varchar);
insert into  regex_test values (1, '1606824000000'), (2, '2021-09-29');

 select * from regex_test ;
 id |     fld_1     
----+---------------
  1 | 1606824000000
  2 | 2021-09-29

select 
    id, 
    case when fld_1 ~* '^[0-9]*$' then 
        to_timestamp(fld_1::bigint/1000) 
    else 
        fld_1::timestamp end as ts_fld 
from 
    regex_test;
 id |         ts_fld         
----+------------------------
  1 | 2020-12-01 04:00:00-08
  2 | 2021-09-29 00:00:00-07
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this query help you

```sql
with data as (
  select
    json_array_elements(data->'Table1'->'Details')->>'closeDate' as closedate 
  from your_table
)
select 
  case when closedate::text ~ '^[0-9]+$' then 
    to_timestamp(closedate::numeric / 1000)::date 
  else 
    closedate::date 
  end 
from data;
```

Comment: I have the query ```case when x.closedate::text similar to '^[0-9]+$' then 
    to_timestamp(x.closedate::bigint/1000)::date
  else 
    x.closedate::date end as transactionclosedate,``` but am getting an error message: date/time field value out of range: "1605657600000"

Answer (score 0):

Either of the other answers would be ok providing that only the specified formats exist. However, containing those formats requires a text field; which may contain anything. It is dangerous to assume if the content is not 13 digits then it is a valid formatted ISO date. I would validate that as well (and verify digits length).

```
select id, 
     , case when closedate ~* '^[0-9]{13}$' then 
                 to_timestamp(closedate::bigint/1000)
            when is_valid_iso_date(closedate) then  
                 closedate::timestamp
            else 
                 '-infinity'::timestamp      -- or whatever to indicate Invalid Date. 
  from  <your table> ;
```

The problem being that `is_valid_iso_date` function. It turns out however I had to create just that a couple years ago, I'll make the result available [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=b5d46fa831430240aeea417d2a3d83a9).

DISCLAIMER: While the function has given no known erroneous results it has NOT been exhaustively tested.

Comment: it is validated that all the other dates are in the 13 digit format, there are however a few blank dates and one date that is just 0. That case statement is working for close dates in the 13 digit format - but I am  having trouble returning the rest of the dates where the format is in  YYYY-MM-DD

Comment: Do not just say you are having trouble, the only reply would be "Ok, So". Tell what you are getting: an error, incorrect results, something else. Post any complete message, best by updating the question, then a small comment to that effect.  Aso post the exact input your having trouble with, what you are getting and what you expect, all as text - **no images**.

Comment: updated the question